# Tirar foto na aplicação android e salvar em uma pasta dentro do projeto (No drawable por exemplo)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Sou novo em programação android e estou desenvolvendo um projeto simples onde o usuário tira uma foto qualquer. Assim que a foto for tirada e o usuário tiver confirmado, queria que salvasse em uma pasta dentro do projeto mesmo (talvez na pasta drawable por exemplo), e salvasse no banco de dados com o nome da imagem para ser usado mais pra frente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde eu sei não é possível escrever nada no drawable ou em qualquer outro diretório da aplicação pois fica dentro do APK. O ideal seria salvar esta foto no armazenamento do aparelho. A [documentação do android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) explica como fazer isso.